# Docker Registry does not have a custom hostname

Tags: windows, docker, docker-registry

I'm trying to configure a local container registry for development purposes, but by specifying the --hostname I can't reach the container.

```
docker run -d -p 5000:5000 `
--hostname docker-container-registry.local `
--restart=always `
--name registry `
-v C:\Programs\tools\docker\ContainerRegistry\auth:/auth `
-v C:\Programs\tools\docker\ContainerRegistry\certs:/certs `
-e "REGISTRY_AUTH=htpasswd" `
-e "REGISTRY_AUTH_HTPASSWD_REALM=Registry Realm" `
-e REGISTRY_AUTH_HTPASSWD_PATH=/auth/htpasswd `
-e REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_CERTIFICATE=/certs/domain.crt `
-e REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_KEY=/certs/domain.key `
registry:2
```

in C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc

```
# Added by Docker Desktop
192.168.1.2 host.docker.internal
192.168.1.2 gateway.docker.internal


192.168.1.2 docker-container-registry.local
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to change the Http ports!

```
docker run -d `
-p 443:443 `
--hostname docker-container-registry.local `
--restart=always `
--name registry `
-v C:\Programs\tools\docker\ContainerRegistry\auth:/auth `
-v C:\Programs\tools\docker\ContainerRegistry\certs:/certs `
-e REGISTRY_HTTP_ADDR=0.0.0.0:443 `
-e "REGISTRY_AUTH=htpasswd" `
-e "REGISTRY_AUTH_HTPASSWD_REALM=Registry Realm" `
-e REGISTRY_AUTH_HTPASSWD_PATH=/auth/htpasswd `
-e REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_CERTIFICATE=/certs/domain.crt `
-e REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_KEY=/certs/domain.key `
registry:2
```